# vhost configuration for owncloud

Tags: apache-2.2, php, phusion-passenger

I'm using `apache2` for hosting owncloud. I configured a vhost file for owncloud, but every time I go on the site my browser downloads a ruby file.

Here is my vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName http://rsserver.fritz.box
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/

    <Directory /var/www/owncloud/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
       <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
      </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Apache error log tells me:

```
[Sat Jun 16 20:46:04 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/owncloud/core/templates/403.php
```

`mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Just to make it clear, are you trying to install this: [Owncloud](http://owncloud.org/)? Because if so...this is written in php, not ruby.

Comment: You are right. I mixed it up with `gitlab`.